# Explorer Without Bottom Taskbar in Python

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, taskbar

I have a python -tkinter program which is operating in full screen, but when I pass a command line

```
(window, command=os.startfile("C:\Program Files"))
```

the windows taskbar always shows up with it, and takes it out of full screen modus

is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: Please attach your code above.

Comment: (window, command=os.startfile("C:\Program Files"))

Comment: ***any way I can fix this?***: Don't use `os.startfile(...`.

Comment: How you are making your tkinter window fullscreen??